# Bernoulli trials total probability

Tags: binomial-distribution

Let X be a binomial random variable with parameters $n = 6$ and $p = 0.4$. We have

$P(X=0)=0.0467$

$P(X=1)=0.1866$

$P(X=2)=0.3110$

$P(X=2)=0.2765$

$P(X=2)=0.1382$

$P(X=2)=0.0369$

$P(X=6)=0.0041$

Why is $P(X=6)$ $\neq$ $1-P(X=0)$?

Say we have a sample of $6$ resistors and probability that a resistor functions = $0.4$. Then there is a $P(X=0)=0.0467$ that no resistors are functioning and there is a $P(X=6)=0.0041$ that all resistors are functioning. So why is $P(X=6$) $\neq$ $1-P(X=0)$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that only some resistor fail but not all resistor fail. For example, it is possible that exactly $2$ resistor fails.

Also, those values do sum up to $1$.

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: We have $P(X=0)+\ldots P(X=6)=1$ right? it is possible that $P(X=1)$ takes positive value isn't it.

Comment: ok, now I see the question has been changed.

Comment: Apologies, I revert back to my original question. I was confusing with another issue.

Comment: we know the probability is nonnegative. we shouldn't have $P(X=0)+P(X=6)=1$, we require $P(X=0)+P(X=1)+\ldots+P(X=6)=1$ and we know that $P(X=1)>0$.